# Camel onException() not triggered

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

I'm trying to test my onException code, but it isn't triggered under unit test. I can doCatch() the exception in the route, but otherwise it's just passed back to the unit test code.
I've boiled it down to little more than a hardcoded throwException() and log() statement, but no luck. Using Camel 2.17.1.

any ideas?

route:

```
@Component
public class BookingSummaryRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
[...]
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    errorHandler(killSwitchErrorHandlerBuilder);

    onException(Exception.class)
            .description("We can get here functional exception and we mustn't send any mail in this case.")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "blahblah")
            .handled(true)
            /*.filter().method(exceptionAnalyserService, "isFunctionalException(${exception})")
                .to(DIRECT_FUNCTIONAL_EXCEPTION)
                .stop()
            //not functional exception*/
            .to("direct:dlq.fatal-error")
    ;

    from("activemq:queue:routemod.spot-booking.summary?concurrentConsumers=1")
            .routeId(BOOKING_SUMMARY_ENTRY_ROUTE)
            .description("Requests and receives a booking summary report")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "blah")
            .throwException(new ConfigurationException("something"))
    ;
```

Unit test:

```
public class BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
[...]
private static final String MOCKED_ENTRYPOINT = "direct:mock-entry";

//under test
@InjectMocks
private BookingSummaryRouteBuilder builder;
[...]
@Override
public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    return true;
}

@Before
public void setUpAdviceWith() throws Exception {

    AdviceWithRouteBuilder adviceWithConfig = new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith(MOCKED_ENTRYPOINT);
            interceptSendToEndpoint("tofalink:dummy")
                    .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                    .to(toFalink);
            }
    };

    context.getRouteDefinition(builder.BOOKING_SUMMARY_ENTRY_ROUTE).adviceWith(context, adviceWithConfig);
    context.start();
}


@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    builder.setDiffsEndpoint(diffsEndpoint);
    builder.setMainframeFacxml(mainframeFacxml);

    return builder;
}

/**
 * No agency found
 */
@Test
public void thatGeneralExceptionRouteInvokedWhenThereIsNoAgency() throws InterruptedException {
    deadLetterChannel.expectedMessageCount(1);
    diffsEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(0);
    doThrow(new ConfigurationException("test"))
            .when(agencyFalinkController).loadByAlphaID(any());

    template.sendBodyAndHeader(MOCKED_ENTRYPOINT, BSH_ID, "scheduleRevisionId", SCHEDULE_REVISION_ID);


    verifyZeroInteractions(killSwitchErrorHandlerBuilder);
    diffsEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    deadLetterChannel.assertIsSatisfied();

}
```

log output:

```
2017-09-13 09:49:52,692 INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
2017-09-13 09:49:52,781  INFO main routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest:220 - ********************************************************************************
2017-09-13 09:49:52,782  INFO main routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest:221 - Testing: thatGeneralExceptionRouteInvokedWhenThereIsNoAgency(com.mediaocean.spectra.mediaservices.routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest)
2017-09-13 09:49:52,782  INFO main routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest:222 - ********************************************************************************
2017-09-13 09:49:53,103  WARN main converter.DefaultTypeConverter:165 - Overriding type converter from: InstanceMethodTypeConverter: public java.lang.Class com.mediaocean.falink.converters.BasicConverters.convertClass(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException to: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Class com.mediaocean.spectra.killswitch.routes.converters.BasicConverters.convertClass(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
2017-09-13 09:49:53,123  INFO main converter.DefaultTypeConverter:56 - Loaded 194 type converters
2017-09-13 09:49:53,519  INFO main routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest:333 - Skipping starting CamelContext as isUseAdviceWith is set to true.
2017-09-13 09:49:53,524  INFO main builder.AdviceWithTasks:336 - AdviceWith replace input from [activemq:queue:routemod.spot-booking.summary?concurrentConsumers=1] --> [direct:mock-entry]
2017-09-13 09:49:53,534  INFO main model.RouteDefinition:292 - AdviceWith route after: Route(bookingSummaryEntrypoint)[[From[direct:mock-entry]] -> [OnException[[class java.lang.Exception] -> [Log[blahblah], To[direct:dlq.fatal-error]]], InterceptSendToEndpoint[direct:dlq.fatal-error -> [To[mock://dlq.fatal-error]]], InterceptSendToEndpoint[fromfalink:bar -> [To[mock://fromFalink]]], InterceptSendToEndpoint[tofalink:dummy -> [To[mock://toFalink]]], ThrowException[mo.core.exception.ConfigurationException], SetHeader[scheduleRevisionLogId, simple{Simple: revisionId=${header.scheduleRevisionId}}], SetHeader[shortDescription, simple{Simple: request summary for revision ${header.scheduleRevisionId}}], Log[${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} Starting booking summary request], SetHeader[burstSaleshouse, simple{Simple: ${body}}], Filter[{header{summaryWorkflow} != isSummaryRefresh} -> [Bean[statusService]]], Bean[falinkController], Log[${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} Headers after FALink is set: ${headers}], Bean[bookingSummaryRequestController], Log[${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} After bookingSummaryRequestController: ${body}], Bean[falinkAssistant], Log[${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} XML version of request: ${body}], To[tofalink:dummy], Log[${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} FALink version: ${body}], Bean[agencyFalinkController], To[mock://mainframe.facxml], RemoveHeader[password], Log[BSH ${header.burstSaleshouse}, Revision ${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} Received booking summary], Log[${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} Booking summary request after tomainframe: ${body}], To[fromfalink:bar], Log[${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} Booking summary request after fromfalink: ${body}], Bean[falinkAssistant], Log[${header.scheduleRevisionLogId} Booking summary request after falinkAssistant: ${body}], Bean[bookingSummaryResponseController], SetBody[simple{Simple: $body.burstSaleshouseId}], Log[BODY IS: ${body}], RemoveHeaders[*], To[mock://activemq:diffs]]]
2017-09-13 09:49:53,535  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:2794 - Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2017-09-13 09:49:53,537  INFO main management.DefaultManagementStrategy:238 - JMX is disabled
2017-09-13 09:49:53,690  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:3033 - AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
2017-09-13 09:49:53,690  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:3043 - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2017-09-13 09:49:53,712  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:3564 - Route: bookingSummaryEntrypoint started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://mock-entry]
2017-09-13 09:49:53,712  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:3564 - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://functionalException]
2017-09-13 09:49:53,713  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:2834 - Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started.
2017-09-13 09:49:53,714  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:2835 - Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.178 seconds
2017-09-13 09:54:13,443  INFO main bookingSummaryEntrypoint:159 - blah
2017-09-13 09:49:53,772  INFO main routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest:363 - ********************************************************************************
2017-09-13 09:49:53,772  INFO main routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest:364 - Testing done: thatGeneralExceptionRouteInvokedWhenThereIsNoAgency(com.mediaocean.spectra.mediaservices.routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest)
2017-09-13 09:49:53,772  INFO main routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest:365 - Took: 0.253 seconds (253 millis)
2017-09-13 09:49:53,772  INFO main routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest:392 - ********************************************************************************
2017-09-13 09:49:53,772  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:3060 - Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
2017-09-13 09:49:53,773  INFO main impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy:196 - Starting to graceful shutdown 2 routes (timeout 10 seconds)
2017-09-13 09:49:53,778  INFO Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - ShutdownTask impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy:669 - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://functionalException]
2017-09-13 09:49:53,778  INFO Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - ShutdownTask impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy:669 - Route: bookingSummaryEntrypoint shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://mock-entry]
2017-09-13 09:49:53,779  INFO main impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy:260 - Graceful shutdown of 2 routes completed in 0 seconds
2017-09-13 09:49:53,782  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:3145 - Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 0.247 seconds
2017-09-13 09:49:53,782  INFO main impl.DefaultCamelContext:3146 - Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.010 seconds

org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-LO-PC-NRAK-53517-1505292592827-0-2]

at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1706)
at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:660)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:471)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:467)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:165)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:159)
at com.mediaocean.spectra.mediaservices.routes.BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest.thatGeneralExceptionRouteInvokedWhenThereIsNoAgency(BookingSummaryRequestRouteTest.java:240)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: mo.core.exception.ConfigurationException: something
at com.mediaocean.spectra.mediaservices.routes.BookingSummaryRouteBuilder.configure(BookingSummaryRouteBuilder.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.checkInitialized(RouteBuilder.java:403)
at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.configureRoutes(RouteBuilder.java:343)
at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.addRoutesToCamelContext(RouteBuilder.java:326)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$1.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:835)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$1.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:832)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2867)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:832)
at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:326)
at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:239)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
```

Comment: Hard to say without debugging and seeing the logs but have a look at the unit tests. They usually give hints to their inner working. https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/onexception/OnExceptionRouteTest.java

Comment: Where are you actually sending a message down the route?

Comment: Is the test failing?

Comment: Julian, sending the message via template.sendBodyAndHeader().

Comment: user3206236, the exception is passed back to the test method, the log statement in onException() is not triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I managed to make some progress on this. The problem seems to be with my errorHandlerBuilder. I replaced the killswitch one it with a basic loggingErrorHandler() and the onException log statement now triggers.

My killSwitchErrorHandlerBuilder is an @Mock, and I wasn't programming it to return an ErrorHandler - as i wasn't expecting it to be triggered in this test. But I guess it breaks the context if it returns a null.

***UPDATE*** fixed by setting a DefaultErrorHandlerBuilder in the RouteBuilder instead of a mock.